# Optimal merging of two dictionaries (but into first, async out problem)

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a dictionary A and need to add elements from B, both are of the same IDictionary type. If its of any consequence, A is empty so there is no data to preserve or potential key conflicts.

I cannot merge them into a third, as proposed by other solutions, for other reasons (async method I use does not support out parameters and I cannot use `Task<(bool, IDictionary<TKey, T>)>` approach as I have to call this task multiple (many) times in parallel as part of the `List<Task<bool>>` for different lookup objects with WhenAll/Aggregate result in the end. `T` types have no common ancestor, being POCO classes, and I really do not want to cast them all from `IDictionary<bool, object>`. So I have to give the async method an already created dictionary to populate.

The approach I used is manual iteration through the results and adding elements to non-out supplied dictionary which was already precreated.

```
static async Task<bool> InternalLoadSqlDictionary<TKey, T>(IContextFactory dbContextFactory, IDictionary<TKey, T> outputSink, Func<T, TKey> keySelector) where T: class 
    {
    ...

    await using var dbc = dbContextFactory.GetContext();
    var result = await dbc.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    foreach (var e in result) outputSink.Add(keySelector(e), e);
    return true;
```

This seems suboptimal to me. Is there some way to do this more efficiently, reinitialize dictionary with new data without destroying the reference, etc. Then I could potentially use `.ToDictionaryAsync(keySelector)` instead of using temporary lists.

Comment: Try following :             Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            Dictionary<string, int> dict3 = dict1.Concat(dict2).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

Comment: @jdweng that is merging two dictionaries into third.

Comment: You can always make the output of the last statement dict1 instead of dict3.

Comment: @jdweng, you cannot. As I explained, that would require me to send the result as `out`, which async method does not support.

Comment: You do not need out when passing classes.  You can modify a class object inside a method and the changes will  be recognized outside the method.  I'm not sure it will work with my code so your way may be the other method that works.